# Swizzling methods, that implicitly return a retained object under ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, method-swizzling

For example, lets consider following code under ARC:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSDate (MyEvilHack)

+ (void)load {
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(copyWithZone:));
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(myCopyWithZone:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, newMethod);
}

- (id)myCopyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    id result = [self myCopyWithZone:zone];
    // do customization
    return result;
}

@end
```

In this code, original `copyWithZone:` method is implicitly returns a retained object, because it belongs to `copy` method family. But my `myCopyWithZone:` is not.

I expect crash, but looks like this code works normally. Of course, I can rename my method to avoid confusion. But I am curious what exactly happens under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, ARC examines the method name, applies the Cocoa memory management naming conventions, and determines how a method should behave. For a method that it's compiling, it makes the method obey those conventions. For a method that it's calling, it assumes the method obeys those conventions.

(One can override the conventions using function attributes, but ignore that for now.)

When ARC is compiling your `-myCopyWithZone:`, it determines that such a method should return a +0 reference. When it encounters the call to (apparently) `-myCopyWithZone:`, it assumes that method returns a +0 reference. Since those match, it should neither retain or release anything.  (Well, it may temporarily retain the result, but it must balance that with an autorelease.) As a result, the **actual** +1 reference returned by the original `-copyWithZone:` survives to the caller and the caller was expecting a +1 reference, so that's all good.

You could probably cause ARC to screw up by calling a different method (which would not be effectively renamed by swizzling) that returns a +1 reference. If it were to return that and since the current method is expected to return a +0 reference, it would autorelease it. The caller would not retain it because it was expecting a +1 reference. So the object would be prematurely deallocated, likely leading to a crash.